# Find $E(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\})$, where $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. uniform on $(1,3)$

Tags: integration

> Let $X_i$, $i = 1,...,n$ be i.i.d. $U[1,3]$ rv’s. Find the expected
>   value of the minimum rv, $Z = \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$.

[image]

This is where I am stuck: I can’t get the integral of t.fz(t)[image]

Note: that I tried the integration by parts method but it did not work.

Comment: I voted this down, because OP gave no proper feedback and wasted my time and that of Satish.

Answer (score 3):

You have two main options:

**1.** Either use the definition you have in mind, that is,

> $$E(Z)=\int_\mathbb Rt\,f_Z(t)\,dt$$

which leads to $$E(Z)=\int_1^3t\,\frac n2\left(\frac{3-t}2\right)^{n-1}dt$$ which, thanks to the change of variable $$u=\frac{3-t}2\qquad t=3-2u\qquad dt=2du$$ becomes $$E(Z)=\int_0^1(3-2u)\frac n2u^{n-1}2du=\left.\left(3u^n-\frac{2n}{n+1}u^{n+1}\right)\right|_0^1=3-\frac{2n}{n+1}=\frac{n+3}{n+1}$$ 
**2.** Or, use the equivalent formula, valid for every almost surely nonnegative random variable $Z$,

> $$E(Z)=\int_0^\infty P(Z\geqslant t)\,dt$$

which leads to $$E(Z)=1+\int_1^3\left(\frac{3-t}2\right)^ndt$$ which, thanks to the same change of variable, becomes $$E(Z)=1+\int_0^1u^n2du=1+\frac2{n+1}=\frac{n+3}{n+1}$$

**Sanity checks:**

- Both methods give the same result.
- For $n=1$, $E(Z)=2$ (why?).
- The quantity $E(Z)$ is a decreasing function of the positive integer $n$ (why?).
- When $n\to\infty$, $E(Z)\to1$ (why?).
- (Slightly more astute than the rest) For $n=0$, $E(Z)=3$ (why?).